# Issue with laravel app hosting error in symfony files

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I tried to host a laravel app on cpanel. It works fine on my localhost. 
I uploaded all the files to the file manager and set directory root to laravelapp/public.
I was getting a error 500 with the message 
"`PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Larapack\Hooks\RawOutput::doWrite($message, $newline) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output::doWrite(string $message, bool $newline)`"

Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the app? Did you just upload the files, if so did you also reupload your vendor folder? Because it seems as if some of your dependancies are out of date.

If you've got access to a console on your server I'd suggest you run `composer install` or `composer update` if you've got a different php version on your server.

Comment: I just uploaded files to the directory. I also tried reuploading vendor files. The error persists. and I dont have console on my server